# How to find the concrete class of a method parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have the following class structure:

```
public interface Incoming<P extends Processor> {
   void doSomething(P p);
}

public interface Processor<I extends Incoming> {
      void process(I i);
}

public class MyIncoming implements Incoming<MyProcessor>
{
   public void doSomething(MyProcessor p) { .. }
}

public class MyProcessor implements Processor<MyIncoming> {
 public void process(MyIncoming i) { .. }
}
```

Now in another class I pass an Instance of MyIncoming that is supposed to initialize the type passed for the Processor it has defined in doSomething()?

Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying that you have a variable of type `MyIncoming` or a variable of type `Incoming`? If you have a variable of type `MyIncoming`, you know that the type is `MyProcessor`.

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding the question. Please be a bit more detailed with the problem you're having

Comment: One more class should clear the problem: class A<T extends Incoming> { public void perform (T t) {  .. } } - Now here we need to find the type of T passed and then call the concrete Processor on t?

Comment: Don't add important informations as comment. Their place is in your question so [edit] it to include that informations.

Comment: `and then call the concrete Processor on t`. Ok so if I understand correctly, for each concrete type of `Incoming`, you have a specific instance of `Processor` `p`, and you want to find out the type of `t`, get the corresponding `p`, and call  `p.process(t)`?

Comment: And the following prints Incoming not MyIncoming: Method m = requestedEvent.getClass ().getDeclaredMethod ("doSomething", Incoming.class);
                Class clz = m.getParameterTypes ()[0];
                System.out.println("Event Type = " + requestedEvent.getClass ().getName ());
                Type[] type = m.getGenericParameterTypes ();
                System.out.println("Type = " + type[0].getTypeName ());
                }

Comment: @PaulBoddington - Yes that is correct.

Comment: I will repeat since you may missed my previous comment: don't add important informations as comment. Add them to your question by using [edit] option (it is below your post). Also comments don't properly support code formatting which is additional reason to not use them for code examples.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see with your code is that you are using the raw types `Incoming` and `Processor`.

```
public interface Incoming<P extends Processor> {
   void doSomething(P p);               ^^
}                               that is a raw type!
```

One way to get rid of those raw types is to make both `Incoming` and `Processor` have two type parameters, but it's very complicated.

```
public interface Incoming<I extends Incoming<I, P>, P extends Processor<I, P>> {
    void doSomething(P p);
}

public interface Processor<I extends Incoming<I, P>, P extends Processor<I, P>> {
    void process(I i);
}
```

Now to your actual question. You've said that for each concrete implementation of `Incoming` you have a specific instance of `Processor`, and for a variable `t` of type `Incoming`, you want to be able to find out that instance `x` and call `x.process(t);`. I'm sure that this can be done with reflection, but I can't see the point. You can just make `getProcessor` a method of `Incoming`.

```
public interface Incoming<I extends Incoming<I, P>, P extends Processor<I, P>> {
    void doSomething(P p);
    P getProcessor();
}
```

Now you can write concrete implementations.

```
public class MyIncoming implements Incoming<MyIncoming, MyProcessor>
{
    private static final MyProcessor PROCESSOR = new MyProcessor();

    @Override
    public void doSomething(MyProcessor p) { }

    @Override
    public MyProcessor getProcessor() { return PROCESSOR; }
}

public class MyProcessor implements Processor<MyIncoming, MyProcessor> {

    @Override
    public void process(MyIncoming i) { }
}
```

Now, if you have a generic class

```
class A<I extends Incoming<I, P>, P extends Processor<I, P>>
```

and, within `A`, you have a variable `i` of type `I`, you can do

```
i.getProcessor().process(i);
```

This works, but personally I think circular dependencies of the form `TypeA<B extends TypeB>` / `TypeB<A extends TypeA>` are unnecessarily convoluted, and the generics here actually work against you. It may preserve your sanity if you just make `Incoming` and `Processor` non-generic interfaces and use casting where necessary.

Comment: One reason of not putting getProcessor() in the Incoming interface was that it would not enforce that the Processor type passed in the doSomething() has to be the same that is returned by the getProcessor().

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `getProcessor()` returns `P`. `doSomething` accepts `P`.